# Kivy Image size changed automatically

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to the Kivy framework and have an issue with the size of the loaded `Image` on my canvas. I have a png image of size 647x1778, and load it into a custom widget as follows:

```py
class CharWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.glyph = kwargs.pop("glyph")
        Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.path = "/tmp/satie.png"
        self.png = Image(source=self.path)
        self.add_widget(self.png)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.png.pos = (touch.x, touch.y)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, .5)
            Rectangle(pos=self.png.pos, size=(self.glyph["width"], self.glyph["height"]))

class SatieApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        with parent.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0)
            parent.add_widget(CharWidget(glyph=Char(name="clefs.G", font="haydn").glyph))
        return parent
```

But when I click on the window the image size is smaller that it's original size. I don't understand where this re-scaling happens, how can I prevent it. The original size is for instance in the `texture_size` but doing `self.png.size = self.png.texture_size` i.e. resizing the image size has no effect. Can any one help understanding this?

Comment: What is `Char` (and what `["width"]`/`["height"]` does it have)? Maybe you meant `self.png` not `self.glyph` when setting the `Rectangle`s `size`.

Comment: `Char` is an object which contains a glyph of a SVG font. The imprtant part to know is that it's `"width", "height"` is the original size of the image = 647x1778